# Делаю войс ассистента и выдает ошибку

Tags: python, vosk

Всем привет, я только на пути изучения Python, решил сделать голосового ассистента.
выдает вот такую вот ошибку
[image: Ошибка]

---

Список устройств, я выбрал правильно 1 и 3.
[image: Ошибка]
я понимаю, что динамики не являются устройством ввода, но по гайду  делаю и у человека все работают, устройства в таком же порядке.
Использую Python 3.9.12

---

вот код
я пробовал в `device = sd.default.device = 1, 3` убрать = 1, 3. Значит должно выбрать устройство по умолчанию, не помогло.

---

```
import sounddevice as sd
import vosk
from vosk import Model, KaldiRecognizer

q = queue.Queue()

model = vosk.Model('model_small')

device = sd.default.device = 1, 3          # sd.default.device = 1, 3 /////input, output # Устройства, которые использую 1 = Миколфон, 3 Динамики. Выбор по умолчанию
samplerate = int(sd.query_devices(device[1], 'input')['default_samplerate'])
#48000

def callback(indata, frames, time, status):

    q.put(bytes(indata))


with sd.RawInputStream(samplerate=samplerate, blocksize = 48000, device=device[1],
            dtype="int16", channels=1, callback=callback):
    # после того, как микро прослушает 48000 сэмплов, их необходмо куда-то передать - 'callback'

    rec = vosk.KaldiRecognizer(model, samplerate)
    while True:
        data = q.get()
        if rec.AcceptWaveform(data):
            print(rec.Result())
        else:
            print(rec.PartialResult())
```

Answer (score 0):

`device` у вас кортеж `(1, 3)`. Значит `device[1]` - это `3`. А устройство `3` - это динамики, так что оно правильно ругается. Попробуйте поменять на `device[0]`:

```
samplerate = int(sd.query_devices(device[0], 'input')['default_samplerate'])
```

Или в явном виде указать `1` в аргументах:

```
samplerate = int(sd.query_devices(1, 'input')['default_samplerate'])
```

Comment: Спасибо, но не помогло(
вот такую ошибку выдает
  File "C:\Users\Musder\Desktop\VoiseAssistant\main.py", line 19, in <module>
    with sd.RawInputStream(samplerate=samplerate, blocksize = 48000, device=device[1],
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
Если единицу в квадратные скобки запихать, то выдает такое
ValueError: Only single values and pairs are allowed

Answer (score 0):

Поменяй это:

```
samplerate = int(sd.query_devices(device[1], 'input')['default_samplerate'])
```

на это:

```
samplerate = int(sd.query_devices(device[*0*], 'input')['default_samplerate'])
```

где, **`0`** означает, что будет использоваться первое значение в `device`.

A так же замени это:

```
with sd.RawInputStream(samplerate=samplerate, blocksize = 48000, device=device[1],
```

на это:

```
with sd.RawInputStream(samplerate=samplerate, blocksize = 48000, device=device[*0*]
```

Comment: надеюсь не поздно)